# Resize images so they would fit screen

Tags: php, html, image, resize

I have few images with different height and width. I want to align them in a set of rows so that the height is the same on all images and the width is calculated so that he all four images would fit screen in one row.

I'm using this code witch works on my big screen but on smaller screen the line is broken in two. I would need to automatically adjust height so the width would fit the screen.

```
<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/ad_vm-va10m_si-sw_01.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/ad_vm-va10m_si-sw_01.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/dada/AD00_vf10H_KP_006.png"><img src="http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/dada/AD00_vf10H_KP_006.png" height="340" ></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_tcc-rr_si-neighbours_01.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_tcc-rr_si-neighbours_01.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_t2m_si-neighbours_01.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_t2m_si-neighbours_01.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</br></br>

<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/ad_vm-va10m_si-sw_02.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/ad_vm-va10m_si-sw_02.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/dada/AD00_vf10H_KP_009.png"><img src="http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/dada/AD00_vf10H_KP_009.png" height="340" ></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_tcc-rr_si-neighbours_02.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_tcc-rr_si-neighbours_02.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_t2m_si-neighbours_02.png"><img src="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/model/aladin/field/as_t2m_si-neighbours_02.png" height="340" ></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</br></br>
```

Here is JSfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/43G3w/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend enclosing each set of 4 images within a `div` with a percentage width. Then use `screen.availWidth` to get the available width and multiply it by the percentage to get the pixel width. Divide this by 4 and use jQuery or Javascript to set the width of each of the images to this (consider using the same class on each image to make this easier). Remember to add `float:left` to each image's CSS to make sure they stay on the same line.

Hope this helps.
C.E.